# How to setup a workspace repository with yarn 2 (berry)

Tags: intellij-idea, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

After some hours with documentation and tutorials I still don't get my project to run.

How to add the core package to the lambda package?

Example repository: https://github.com/benkeil/yarn-berry-workspaces

After `yarn workspace lambda add core` he adds a dependency to the lambda package but IntelliJ says it can't find the module.

And of corse I can't start it: `src/index.ts:1:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'core' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Answer (score 0):

`yarn workspace lambda add core` should do the thing, but your `package.json` has to be corrected, it references the files that don't exist.

- change the `https://github.com/benkeil/yarn-berry-workspaces/blob/main/code/core/package.json` as follows:

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "prebuild": "yarn clean",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prebuild:watch": "yarn prebuild",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  }
}
```

(note the changed `"main"` and `"types"` entries)

- in `yarn-berry-workspaces/blob/main/code/core/` folder, run `tsc`
- restart the IDE

Comment: In my normal project I don't have and want these barrel files. With yarn v1 or npm everything works fine without these fields. Never the less, it has no impact to add these fields.